filtering to only relevant start/end dates inside text string?
I want to use filter formula to search orange table and bring in the relevant data. I am trying to also make sure it searches c2:c7 data in the text strings to pick out dates that fall between the start/end dates in g2:h2.
=IFNA(UNIQUE(FILTER({A2:A7,B2:B7,C2:C7}, (A2:A7=E2)*(D2:D7=F2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(E2,"mm/dd/yyyy"), C2:C7)))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(F2,"mm/dd/yyyy"), C2:C7))))),"")

based on the inputs I set with the dates, I'd expect to see row 2 data, but not row 3 data because row 3 has a comment with no dates between 4/2/24 and 4/7/24. but row 2 data has a 4/4/24 date which falls between the start/end date dropdowns.
any ideas what I am missing? I've provided what I expect the output to look like in green.

here is the link to my sheet


You may try:
=filter(A2:C7, A2:A7=E2, D2:D7=F2,
       byrow(C2:C7,lambda(Σ,or(bycol(split(Σ,char(10)),lambda(Λ,isbetween(--left(Λ,find(" ",Λ)),G2,H2)))))))



Hey! Thank you. I just had a quick question. So I tried to apply this to my actual worksheet, and came up with this:
=filter({'Master Line List'!C:C,'Master Line List'!F:F,'Master Line List'!I:I,'Master Line List'!G:G,'Master Line List'!A:A},'Master Line List'!I:I=G1,'Master LineList'!G:G=H1,byrow({'Master Line List'!C:C,'Master Line List'!F:F,'Master Line List'!I:I,'Master Line List'!G:G,'Master Line ``List'!A:A,lambda(Σ,or(bycol(split(Σ,char(10)),lambda(Λ,isbetween(--left(Λ,find("``",Λ)),i1,j1)))))))
but I seem to be getting a formula parse error?
